# Increase a series each time a function is called

Tags: javascript

I have divs displayed with a PHP script using foreach. Each div should call a JavaScript function and generate a new div unic with id but I don't know how to increment the series. I need a incrementing loop each time the a div calls the function. Is that possible?

This is the .php file:

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     foreach($objects as $key => $ar1)
      {
        countdown_clock_abs(<?php echo $ar1['timespamSale']; ?>,1);
      }
  </script>
 </body>

</html>
```

This is the JavaScript:

```
function countdown_clock_abs(time, format)
{
     // I expected the foreach loop do the job but the php it is loaded before the javascrip is launched. So clearly this is not the way to do it.
     html_code = '<div id="countdown<?php echo ar1['id']; ?>"></div>';

     document.write(html_code);

     countdown_abs(time, format);                
}
function countdown_abs(time, format)
{
var d=new Date();
var Target_Time = (time);
var Now_time = ((d.getTime()));

Time_Left = Math.round(Target_Time-(Now_time)/1000);

     if(Time_Left < 0)
        Time_Left = 0;

     var innerHTML = '';

     switch(format)
           {
           case 0:
                innerHTML = Time_Left + ' seconds';
                break;
           case 1:
                days = Math.floor(Time_Left / (60 * 60 * 24));
                Time_Left %= (60 * 60 * 24);
                hours = Math.floor(Time_Left / (60 * 60));
                Time_Left %= (60 * 60);
                minutes = Math.floor(Time_Left / 60);
                Time_Left %= 60;
                seconds = Time_Left;

                dps = 's'; hps = 's'; mps = 's'; sps = 's';

                if(days == 1) dps ='';
                if(hours == 1) hps ='';
                if(minutes == 1) mps ='';
                if(seconds == 1) sps ='';

                innerHTML = days + ' day' + dps + ' ';
                innerHTML += hours + ' hour' + hps + ' ';
                innerHTML += minutes + ' minute' + mps + ' and ';
                innerHTML += seconds + ' second' + sps;
                break;
                default: innerHTML = Time_Left + ' seconds';
           }                   

        document.getElementById('countdown<?php echo ar1['id']; ?>').innerHTML = innerHTML;     

        setTimeout('countdown_abs(' + time + ',' + format + ');', 50);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the signature of your method to match `function countdown_clock_abs(time, format, id)`. Now in your first block of code, you can pass the counter to the id param